# Javascript/AJAX function that works in Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have these two buttons that a user can click to either approve/deny somebody on a site, and the code works perfect in IE, but when I try and use firefox, nothing at all happens when I click the buttons.

the javascipt/ajax code is:

```
        function ApproveOrDenyStudent(i, action){
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari                
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }                                                

            var newStudentEmail = "newStudentEmail" + i;

            var emailField = document.getElementById(newStudentEmail);
            var email = emailField ? emailField.value : '';       



            // Approve/deny the user
            if (action == 0){      
                xmlhttp.open("GET","ApproveStudent.php?email="+email,true); 
            }
            else if (action == 1){
                xmlhttp.open("GET","DenyStudent.php?email="+email,true); 
            }
            xmlhttp.send();
            window.location.reload();
        }
```

any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Can I point out that you are not actually validating whether the GET request completed successfully. You should probably reload only if the change was successful.

Answer (score 2):

You got a race condition!

```
xmlhttp.send();
window.location.reload();
```

You are making an asynchronous call. You are making the Ajax request and replacing the page right away! The call to the server is not getting out.

Reload the page when the request is complete.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Oh! I completely missed that! Thanks!...Just out of curiosity, what is a ready state of 4?